Is there any cost/downside with increasing vector tiles accuracy (extent)?
I need to come up with a strategy for loading a lot of vector tiles that contain a lot of features.
One of the strategies I am considering is overzooming.
In general, if I understand correctly, with overzooming to each new level, I lose precision by a factor of 2 in each direction (X,Y).
For example, if I have a tilesource for zoom level 15, then on zoom level 16 my point is 2^1 times bigger (in one axis direction), on 17 its 2^2 times bigger, on 18 2^3, etc...
So, if I want to overzoom 5 levels, I will introduce inaccuracy of 32x32 pixels (and whatever that translates to in terms of ground distance).
[someone please correct me if I got this math wrong]
One way to address this is to increase the extent parameter in ST_AsMVTGeom which I use to generate tiles.
Is there any cost/downside related to increasing extent?

I usually generate my vector tiles using tippecanoe, so I'm not an expert on postgis-generated tiles. In my use cases, it is generally bad if the tiles are bigger than a certain size. This makes HTTP requests slow, makes querying the tiles slow, and in general heavier on frontend.

@zabop are you talking about tile size ( 512x512 e.g.) or tile coordinates precision (aka extent or tile resolution)?

I am not familiar with other tools than tippecanoe, but in tippecanoe I believe those concepts are tightly connected: tiles are n by n point grids, and resolution is determined by how close those points are to each other. So maybe I mean both? But again, if whatever you are using is very different from tippecanoe, then my experience with tippecanoe might not be relevant at all.

@zabop with tippecanoe its this part: https://github.com/felt/tippecanoe#tile-resolution .
